# Center images inside a div with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I have a section in my login form to log in with social networks like Facebook and Google, but the problem is the I can't center the icons under the div and keep it responsive always.

Please help me!!.

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row my-5 justify-content-center">
  <div class="text-md-right text-sm-left col-sm-6 col-md-5">
    <p>Sign With</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#" class="">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/y5ZdM7r/ICON-FB.png" class="float-center">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/c3g5tdd/ICON-GOOGLE.png" class="ml-2 float-center">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bootstrap classes, add: `d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center` to the `div` wrapping the `a` tags.

In regular CSS without Bootstrap, this is how you center:

You should give the parent `div` (the one wrapping the `a` tags) the following CSS properties:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!